# Pi NAS: Access over internet

Tags: raspbian, remote, samba

I am running SAMBA on my Pi with a USB HDD. Samba is running fine.

But I wish to be able to access the files from remote location (over internet). My Pi hosts a wordpress site and I can access it over internet.

How can I access my files over internet?

**Update:** Integration to Windows explorer or a web interface (GUI for Samba) might be a good start. I saw something here: http://www.samba.org/samba/GUI/ and not sure if some of them might be for me.

Comment: Do you want to access the files from a web browser (through a UI like Dropbox or Google Drive), or through your file manager (Windows file explorer or Nautilus)?

Comment: I want to get a file and not bothered about how I get it. Integrating in Windows Explorer might be very convenient. But even if I can get a web interface where I can click and download a file over http will be great.

Comment: Whan you say "internet" do you mean LAN or WAN?

Comment: @Kangkan Do you need to have control on those files? I mean, do you need to delete, move, rename, etc.? Or you just want a convenient way download them?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think by far the easiest way to share files is to set up an FTP server.

Unless you want to share files through your Wordpress site. You will have to elaborate further what it is that you want exactly.

To set up an FTP, here you'll find a guide:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server/step9/Install-an-FTP-server/

On the other hand you could just make your Wordpress site host files.
I'm not very familiar with WP, but it's pretty customizable from what I have heard, given that you know some php etc.

Otherwise, you may want to give this a read as an alternative:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downloadmanager/

**update:**
Since it appears you want some kind of web interface, maybe have a look at this project like you suggested in your link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdisk/

A quick google found me this guide for the installation: http://blog.boreas.ro/2009/08/integratum-webdisk-on-rhel-53-x64-using.html

Or look around on github for a "webdisk" project that suits your needs the most.

**EXTRA**

As stated in another answer here, owncloud is also a possible contender.
However it doesn't run all that smooth on a Raspberry Pi, expect 3~5 second page loads with already optimised PHP.

Comment: I do not think FTP is very convenient. However can be used as a work around.

Comment: @Kangkan I agree with Havnar. But from what I understand, you prefer a GUI interface rather than a CLI, don't you?

Comment: Then what is it exactly that you are trying to do?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: +1 and Accepted for the OwnCloud tip. It worked for me and is still working.

Answer (score 4):

- [sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) - there are clients for Linux, Windows, Mac and Android
  you need only ssh server running on RPi.
  With Windows client, you can map RPI as a network drive.
- Using [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is another option.

or

- [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/)

Comment: OwnCloud works on Raspberry Pi??

Comment: Yes, for example: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Owncloud-dropbox-clone/